# Sql query for data

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with videos and every table have a username.

**Example**:

> username | title |
>
> John
>           | My car is the
>   best
>
> John         | My
>   car
>
> John         | My
>   car
>
> Maria        | I
>   like google
>
> Maria        | I like
>   google
>
> Jerry        | I
>   like cheese

How to select username with most data and ordering *desc*?

**Example**:

```
John  -> 3
Maria -> 2
Jerry -> 1
```

Comment: In the future, you should include what queries you tried.

Comment: Sorry, is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
select username, times from
(select username, count(title) as times 
  from yourtable
group by username) qry
order by qry.times desc;
```

Comment: You could mark this answer as correct too...

Answer (score 1):

```
select username,count(*) coun
from theTable
group by username 
order by coun desc
```

Comment: using count as a field name can get problematic since it's a reserved word. I'd suggest using something else as some compilers will balk that this.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, COUNT(1) AS c FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY c DESC